# C# adding a row to a datagridview in another form

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I'm having difficulty trying to pass information from one form in which a user inputs a lot of employee data and presses a Submit button and the information is to display as an added row to a datagridview table.  What can I do to fix this issue?

The code I have at present:

```
Form1:
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

        private void getEmployeedata(Manager manager)
        {
            int age;
            int years;
            int salary;                

            manager.FirstName = firstnameBox.Text;
            manager.LastName = lastnameBox.Text;
            manager.Gender = genderBox.Text;
            manager.Title = titleBox.Text;
            manager.Exempt = exemptBox.Text;

            if (int.TryParse(ageBox.Text, out age))
            {
                manager.Age = age;

                if (int.TryParse(yearsBox.Text, out years))
                {
                    manager.Years = years;

                    if (int.TryParse(salaryBox.Text, out salary))
                    {
                        manager.Salary = salary;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong salary input");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Years input");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong age input");
            }
        }

    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        getEmployeedata(manager);

        EmployeeListing form2 = new EmployeeListing(manager.FirstName, manager.LastName, manager.Gender, manager.Age, manager.Years, manager.Title, manager.Exempt, manager.Salary);
        form2.Show();

    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstnameBox.Text = "";
        lastnameBox.Text = "";
        genderBox.Text = "";
        ageBox.Text = "";
        yearsBox.Text = "";
        titleBox.Text = "";
        exemptBox.Text = "";
        salaryBox.Text = "";
    }

}

class Employee
{
    private string firstName = "";
    private string lastName = "";
    private string gender = "";
    private int age = 0;
    private int years = 0;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }

    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set { gender = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public int Years
    {
        get { return years; }
        set { years = value; }
    }

} //end Employee class

class Manager : Employee
{
    private string title = "";
    private string exempt = "";
    private int salary = 0;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string Exempt
    {
        get { return exempt; }
        set { exempt = value; }
    }

    public int Salary
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; }
    }

} //end Manager class

Form2:

public partial class EmployeeListing : Form
{
    public EmployeeListing(string firstname, string lastname, string gender, int age, int years, string title, string exempt, int salary)
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            employeeList.Rows.Add(firstname, lastname, gender, age, years, title, exempt, salary);                      
    }

 }
```

Comment: What Difficulty? What Issue? can you be more specific....

Comment: Can you show more code for example how `employeeList` is defined and where.. also show the class of Manager. you may have to use the key word `this.firstname, etc.....` to make sure the proper variables are being assigned but can't tell without seeing more relevant code.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm trying to rows of user input to a datagridview on a second form.  Whenever I press the submit button, it pops up a new window showing a datagridview showing only what I currently have inputted on one line.  It isn't creating an accumulating list.

Comment: employeeList is the name of my datagridview table.

Comment: Updated with full code.  Sorry, first time using this site.

Comment: WOW... I really LOVE the else.. MessageBox.. else.. MessageBox sequence. I'm doing a desktop wallpaper with that right now

Comment: I would personally change the property's to use auto properties makes your code so much more manageable and easier to read..

Comment: this line here inside `form1` `manager.Age = age;` I would change to `manager.Age = this.age;` do this for the `age, year, and salary` as well

Comment: This: `condition ? expression_true : expression_false;` can simplify your code from 30 to 3 lines.

`int.TryParse(ageBox.Text, out age) ? manager.Age = age : MessageBox.Show("Wrong age input");
int.TryParse(yearsBox.Text, out years) ? manager.Years = years : MessageBox.Show("Wrong Years input");
int.TryParse(salaryBox.Text, out salary) ? manager.Salary = salary : MessageBox.Show("Wrong salary input");`

Comment: @Toni, I tried to add that to the form as a replacement code but it doesn't seem to allow it.  I get another error:

Answer (score 2):

In your click handler, you are initializing a EmployeeListing form every time you click the button, and you probably only want to do this once.So, keep the instance of your EmployeeListing outside of the click handler and only create one instance of it so that you can access it on subsequent clicks. To keep adding data to the form, you could create a public method on the EmployeeListing form that adds the row data and then call this method from your click handler, using the instance of the form.

This is untested, but just to get you started...

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void getEmployeedata(Manager manager)
        {
            int age;
            int years;
            int salary;   
            EmployeeListing form2;      

            manager.FirstName = firstnameBox.Text;
            manager.LastName = lastnameBox.Text;
            manager.Gender = genderBox.Text;
            manager.Title = titleBox.Text;
            manager.Exempt = exemptBox.Text;

            if (int.TryParse(ageBox.Text, out age))
            {
                manager.Age = age;

                if (int.TryParse(yearsBox.Text, out years))
                {
                    manager.Years = years;

                    if (int.TryParse(salaryBox.Text, out salary))
                    {
                        manager.Salary = salary;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong salary input");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Years input");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong age input");
            }
        }

    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        getEmployeedata(manager);
        if (form2 == null)
        {
            EmployeeListing form2 = new EmployeeListing();
            form2.Show();
        }       

        form2.AddRowData(manager.FirstName, manager.LastName, manager.Gender, manager.Age, manager.Years, manager.Title, manager.Exempt, manager.Salary);
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstnameBox.Text = "";
        lastnameBox.Text = "";
        genderBox.Text = "";
        ageBox.Text = "";
        yearsBox.Text = "";
        titleBox.Text = "";
        exemptBox.Text = "";
        salaryBox.Text = "";
    }

}

class Employee
{
    private string firstName = "";
    private string lastName = "";
    private string gender = "";
    private int age = 0;
    private int years = 0;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }

    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set { gender = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public int Years
    {
        get { return years; }
        set { years = value; }
    }

} //end Employee class

class Manager : Employee
{
    private string title = "";
    private string exempt = "";
    private int salary = 0;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public string Exempt
    {
        get { return exempt; }
        set { exempt = value; }
    }

    public int Salary
    {
        get { return salary; }
        set { salary = value; }
    }

} //end Manager class

public partial class EmployeeListing : Form
{
    public EmployeeListing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                                
    }

    public AddRowData(string firstname, string lastname, string gender, int age, int years, string title, string exempt, int salary)
    {
        employeeList.Rows.Add(firstname, lastname, gender, age, years, title, exempt, salary); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Geo.  That was exactly what I needed to do to fix it.  I removed the instancing of the form and created the method to call for the addition of each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable on the EmployeeListing() constructor and set the DataSource:

```
public EmployeeListing(string firstname, string lastname, string gender, int age, int years, string title, string exempt, int salary)
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            //employeeList.Rows.Add(firstname, lastname, gender, age, years, title, exempt, salary);                      

            DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
            dtSource.Columns.Add("firstname", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("lastname", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("gender", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("age", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("years", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("exempt", typeof(string));
            dtSource.Columns.Add("salary", typeof(string));
            DataRow dtRow;

            dtRow = dtSource.NewRow();
            dtRow[0] = firstname;
            dtRow[1] = lastname;
            dtRow[2] = gender;
            dtRow[3] = age;
            dtRow[4] = years;
            dtRow[5] = Title;
            dtRow[6] = exempt;
            dtRow[7] = salary;

            dtSource.Rows.Add(dtRow.ItemArray);

            employeeList.DataSource = dtSource;


    }
```

You should also out this in another function and not in the constructor if you will add rows to the gridview more than once.

Comment: You need to keep a member variable of `Form2` or `EmployeeListing` in Form1. Otherwise each time you instantiate `EmployeeListing` to add a Employee it will be in a new instance...